# Single sign on and Single log out using Identity Server 3

Tags: c#, single-sign-on, identityserver3

I am trying out the Identity Server 3 using WS-Fed plugin to do an SSO and SLO. I have the following setup:

1. Identity Server application using WS-Feb plugin.
2. Relaying Party MVC App 1
3. Replaying Party MVC App 2

I have implemented SSO successfully and its working perfectly. Now the issue is that after logging out from my MVC App 1, I can still access my MVC App 2 which I don't want. If user logs out from any of the two apps he/she should logged out from the other app also.

My Identity Server Startup.cs:

```
public class Startup {
    X509Certificate2 LoadCertificate()
    {
        return new X509Certificate2(
            string.Format(@"{0}\bin\identityServer\idsrv3test.pfx", AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory), "idsrv3test");
    }

    void ConfigureWsFederation(IAppBuilder pluginApp, IdentityServerOptions options)
    {
        var factory = new WsFederationServiceFactory(options.Factory);
        factory.UseInMemoryRelyingParties(Clients.GetWsFederation());

        var wsFedOptions = new WsFederationPluginOptions
        {
            IdentityServerOptions = options,
            Factory = factory
        };

        pluginApp.UseWsFederationPlugin(wsFedOptions);
    }

    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        var factory = new IdentityServerServiceFactory();
        factory.UseInMemoryUsers(Users.Get());
        factory.UseInMemoryScopes(Scopes.Get());
        factory.UseInMemoryClients(Clients.GetIdentityServer());

        app.UseIdentityServer(new IdentityServerOptions
        {
            SiteName = "Custom Identity Server",
            SigningCertificate = LoadCertificate(),
            Factory = factory,
            RequireSsl = false,
            PluginConfiguration = ConfigureWsFederation,
            EnableWelcomePage = false
        });

        app.Map("/signoutcleanup", cleanup =>
        {
            cleanup.Run(async ctx =>
            {
                await ctx.Environment.ProcessFederatedSignoutAsync();
            });
        });
    } }
```

Relaying Parties:

```
public static IEnumerable<RelyingParty> GetWsFederation()
{
    return new List<RelyingParty>()
    {
        new RelyingParty
        {
            Realm = "urn:firstwebapp",
            Name = "FirstWebApp",
            Enabled = true,
            ReplyUrl = "http://gauravfirstapp.azurewebsites.net/",
            PostLogoutRedirectUris = new List<string>() { "http://gauravfirstapp.azurewebsites.net/" },
            ClaimMappings = new Dictionary<string, string>()
            {
                { Constants.ClaimTypes.Id, "userid" },
                { Constants.ClaimTypes.Name ,"fullname" },
                { Constants.ClaimTypes.GivenName, "firstname" },
                { Constants.ClaimTypes.FamilyName, "lastname" },
                { Constants.ClaimTypes.Email, "email" },
                { Constants.ClaimTypes.AuthenticationMethod, "authentication" },
                { "role" , "roles" },
            }
        },
        new RelyingParty
        {
            Realm = "urn:secondwebapp",
            Name = "SecondWebApp",
            Enabled = true,
            ReplyUrl = "http://gauravsecondapp.azurewebsites.net/",
            PostLogoutRedirectUris = new List<string>() { "http://gauravsecondapp.azurewebsites.net/" },
            ClaimMappings = new Dictionary<string, string>()
            {
                { Constants.ClaimTypes.Id, "userid" },
                { Constants.ClaimTypes.Name ,"fullname" },
                { Constants.ClaimTypes.GivenName, "firstname" },
                { Constants.ClaimTypes.FamilyName, "lastname" },
                { Constants.ClaimTypes.Email, "email" },
                { Constants.ClaimTypes.AuthenticationMethod, "authentication" },
                { "role" , "roles" },
            }
        }
    };
}
```

MVC App 1 Startup.cs:

```
public class Startup
{
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
        {
            AuthenticationType = "Cookies"
        });

        app.UseWsFederationAuthentication(new WsFederationAuthenticationOptions
        {
            MetadataAddress = "http://gauravdemosso.azurewebsites.net/wsfed/metadata",
            Wtrealm = "urn:firstwebapp",
            SignInAsAuthenticationType = "Cookies",
            SignOutWreply = "http://gauravfirstapp.azurewebsites.net/"
        });
    }
}
```

MVC App 2 Startup.cs:

```
public class Startup
{
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
        {
            AuthenticationType = "Cookies"
        });

        app.UseWsFederationAuthentication(new WsFederationAuthenticationOptions
        {
            MetadataAddress = "http://gauravdemosso.azurewebsites.net/wsfed/metadata",
            Wtrealm = "urn:secondwebapp",
            SignInAsAuthenticationType = "Cookies",
            SignOutWreply = "http://gauravsecondapp.azurewebsites.net"
        });
    }
}
```

What I am missing here?